# Since Blender 2.9 I get random lines in edit mode on Mac Pro

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I think this is related to my outdated display card, but was hoping someone here could verify that before I spend money on an updated version. I have a 2010 Mac Pro 5.1 running Ubuntu v20 and Blender 2.93. The graphics card is a stock Apple Radeon HD 4870 with 512Mb memory. Image render is fine, and graphics in object mode is fine, but when I switch to edit mode, there are random vectors showing up in the mesh. The mesh itself checks out, but is difficult to edit because of the stray lines. Would a newer HD 5970 solve this, or is there another solution?

[image]

Comment: This does not look like a graphics card "glitch", it looks like actual edges as some are selected and some aren't. Could you please share your .blend so we could verify? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: That is exactly my point. The file is fine on my pc with unix and my newer mac mini. The vectors only show up on the old mac pro. I'll try to share the file, but chances are you won't see the stray lines because they are not there – unless you also have an old mac.

Comment: Here's a link to the file on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oyuhtkw8x4h0xwa/stray-vector-test.blend?dl=0

Comment: Ok, that is really weird! Nothing wrong with the file that I can see in Linux version. Sorry, that's all I can offer.